# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv.Internal.Networking.UvException: 'Error -4092 EACCES permission denied'

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, tfs

I am using TFS source control. Today, after I updated code and ran the project, I encountered this error:

[image: This is my capture image]

I am using Visual Studio 2017. My project is Web API .NET Core 2.0.
And this is the error detail:

[image: Error Detail]

Comment: Try running visual studio as administrator

Comment: Thank you, I have run as administrator. But this it is still error.

Comment: @KhoaNguyenAnh did you get anywhere with this? Having a similar issue when running `dotnet run`

Comment: Dear thisextendsthat,
I have not found the solution.Now, I am not use that computer.

Answer (score 2):

We had this issue recently, turned out that the port the Kestrel server was trying to use had somehow now fallen within an excluded port range.

You can view what port ranges have been excluded by running the following in command prompt

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

Once we realised the cause we did try to delete the range we wanted to use using the following (in elevated Administator command prompt)

```
netsh int ip delete excludedportrange protocol=tcp numberofports=100 startport=49909
```

This however resulted in an `Access Denied`.

There doesn't seem to be a way to find out the owner of the excluded port range, however in my instance it was Hyper-V. Once I turned Hyper-V off the ports were released and I could then debug in Visual Studio.

When I re-enabled Hyper-V (because I need it), it registered a different set of port ranges that do not effect the Kestrel server.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issues, there seems the IIS_IUSRS doesn't have access to the specific package.

You can try to grant the access to IIS_IUSRS in the packages directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

we are working with an old version of Kestrel and for us this happens when the web application's listening port dedicated to Kestrel is already used by another application. Simply change the Kestrel default port value (often 5000) to solve the error.